# How to prove Sum of squares of $n$ numbers is unique

Tags: sums-of-squares

I was solving a programming problem where I needed to prove that sum of squares of $n$ numbers is unique. i. e. if calculate the sum of squares of equal number of positive integers then if they are same it means that all numbers are the same.

How do I prove it?

```
The range of numbers is between 0 and 127(inclusive)
or does the range matter?
```

Comment: $$S= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$ is an increasing function for $n>0$

Comment: But $7^2+1^2=5^2+5^2$ !

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but can you find an example with distinct numbers on both sides?

Comment: Or even $3^2+4^2 = 5^2+0^2$

Comment: Sure, $11^2+2^2=10^2+5^2$ or $7^2+4^2=8^2+1^2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ah, that is more satisfying. And now I see how such examples are easily found: $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ is equivalent to $(a-c)(a+c)=(d-b)(b+d)$, so you just look for two different factorizations of a number.

Comment: Find here(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) for the number of representations of an sum of squares

Comment: By the way, I found these examples by looking at complex number multiplications $(a+bi)(c\pm di)$, e.g. $(1+2i)(2\pm3i)$ for the last example.

Comment: If $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ then $a^2-c^2=d^2-b^2$ so that there is a number $n=(a+c)(a-c)=(d+b)(d-b)$. So take a number $n$ and factorise as $n=pq=rs$. We need $p-q$ even and $r-s$ even. Then $a=\frac{p+q}2$, $c=\frac{p-q}2$, $d=\frac{r+s}2$, $b=\frac{r-s}2$ will do.

Comment: So this means the solution that i saw was wrong. I'm sorry